# JS regex get text between characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm using this JS regex `text.match(/|(https:.+?path.+?)|/)[1]` to get a regex of a URL that is in between pipe `|` characters but it's not working.

The text is `||https://url.com/path/value||` but I can't seem to extract the URL from it. I need to have `path` in the middle to identify this particular URL since there are other URLs in the file.

It doesn't have to be a URL that I'm extracting. I mainly would like to know how to extract something from between a pair of characters (`|` in this case).

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? `"||https://url.com/path/value||".match(/\|(https:.+?path\/(.+?))\|/)[2]` **Output:** `value`. Here is a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6cwyvchm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe ("|") characters:

```
text.match(/\|(https:.+?path.+?)\|/)[1]
```

Pipe is a special character that basically means "or". https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 0):

To grab everything between the two sets of `||` then you could use this regex:

```
text.match(/\|\|(.*)\|\|/)
```

The first part `\|\|` matches the characters `||` literally.

The next part `(.*)`matches any character zero or more and groups the result.

The last part `\|\|` matches the closing characters `||` literally.